# How to know when a LazyColumn (or any Composable for that matter) has been touched?

Tags: android, kotlin, focus, android-jetpack-compose, touch-event

I have the following screen built in Compose -

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(heroesViewModel: HeroesViewModel = get()) {

    val searchState by heroesViewModel.searchState.collectAsState()
    val uiState by heroesViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        SearchBar(
            searchState = searchState,
            onQueryChanged = { text ->
                heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.SearchQueryChanged(text))
            },
            onSearchFocusChange = { focused ->
                heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.SearchBarFocusChanged(focused))
            },
            onClearQueryClicked = {
                heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.ClearQueryClicked)
            },
            onBack = {},
            focusRequester
        )

        LazyColumn {
            items(uiState.modelsListResponse ?: listOf()) { model ->
                if (model is HeroListSeparatorModel)
                    HeroesListSeparatorItem(model)
                else if (model is HeroesListModel)
                    HeroesListItem(model) {
                        heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.ListItemClicked(model))
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my SearchBar -

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    searchState: SearchState,
    onQueryChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearchFocusChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onClearQueryClicked: () -> Unit,
    onBack: () -> Unit,
    focusRequester : FocusRequester,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val focused = searchState.focused

    Row(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {

        AnimatedVisibility(visible = focused) {
            BackButton(focusManager, keyboardController, onBack)
        }

        SearchTextField(
            searchState,
            onQueryChanged,
            onSearchFocusChange,
            onClearQueryClicked,
            focusRequester
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun SearchTextField(
    searchState: SearchState,
    onQueryChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearchFocusChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    onClearQueryClicked: () -> Unit,
    focusRequester : FocusRequester,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val focused = searchState.focused
    var query = searchState.query
    val searching = searchState.searching

    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .then(
                Modifier
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .padding(
                        top = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp,
                        start = if (focused.not()) 16.dp else 0.dp,
                        end = 16.dp
                    )
            ),
        color = Color(0xffF5F5F5),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(percent = 50)
    ) {

        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides ContentAlpha.medium) {

            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart,
                modifier = modifier
            ) {

                if (query.isEmpty()) {
                    SearchHint(modifier = modifier.padding(start = 24.dp, end = 8.dp))
                }

                Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) {
                    BasicTextField(
                        value = query,
                        onValueChange = {
                            query = it
                            onQueryChanged(it)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxSize()
                            .weight(1f)
                            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                                onSearchFocusChanged(focusState.isFocused)
                            }
                            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                            .padding(top = 9.dp, bottom = 8.dp, start = 24.dp, end = 8.dp),
                        singleLine = true
                    )
                    when {
                        searching -> {
                            CircularProgressIndicator(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
                                    .width(25.dp)
                                    .size(24.dp)
                            )
                        }

                        query.isNotEmpty() -> {
                            IconButton(onClick = onClearQueryClicked) {
                                Icon(
                                    imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
                                    contentDescription = null
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SearchHint(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    hint: String = "Enter a hero name"
) {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .then(modifier)

    ) {
        Text(
            text = hint,
            color = Color(0xff757575)
        )
    }
}


class SearchState(
    query: String,
    focused: Boolean,
    searching: Boolean,
) {
    
    var query by mutableStateOf(query)
    var focused by mutableStateOf(focused)
    var searching by mutableStateOf(searching)
    
}
```

What I want to achieve is the ability to know when the user has tapped or click anywhere outside of my SearchBar Composable. I want to send an event to the ViewModel so that he recomposes the screen, removing the keyboard and removing the cursor I have on my SearchBar (basically just resetting the focus).

I have tried using the `focusRequester` like I did in my SearchBar but without success as nothing happened, tried using the `clickable {}` block which is not what I need (I need the tap and not the click) and tried using `Modifier.pointerInput` with `detectTapGestures` and it did not work, not at the root LazyColumn and not at the ListItem level.

What I am looking for should be something really easy.

Comment: You want to have a listener on LazyColumn, which hides the keyboard, right?

Comment: @MohammadDerakhshan yeah and removed the cursor focus from the BasicTextField that's inside the SearchBar

Comment: What is the problem when you use `detectTapGestures` on items or LazyColumn? Isn't `onTap` invoked?

Comment: @Thracian just didn't work. I ended up using `isScrollInProgress` variable from `LazyListState` class and when the value was true I removed the focus from where I needed to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer - I ended up using `isScrollInProgress` variable from `LazyListState` class that provides a boolean indicating if the list is currently in scrolling. When the value was true I removed the focus from where I needed to remove it and it worked :)

Attached the solution -

```kotlin
val listState = rememberLazyListState()

...
LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            items(uiState.modelsListResponse ?: listOf()) { model ->
                heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.ListIsScrolling(listState.isScrollInProgress))
                if (model is HeroListSeparatorModel)
                    HeroesListSeparatorItem(model)
                else if (model is HeroesListModel)
                    HeroesListItem(model) {
                        heroesViewModel.submitEvent(HeroesViewModel.UiEvent.ListItemClicked(model))
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `PointerInputModifier` which provides access to the underlying MotionEvents originally dispatched to Compose.

```
      Text(modifier = Modifier
          .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->

              when (motionEvent.action) {

                   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                   // When the user touches the composable
                   }
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                   // When the user removes touch from the composable
                   }
              }
              true
         },
           text = "Click Me!"
       )
```

Inside `pointerInteropFilter` block `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is triggered when user touches on the composable.